# On the Bayesian setup in inference

Tags: bayesian, inference

I've been trying to get into the chapter 4 in Lehmann's *Theory of point estimation*, but I can't seem to understand his presentation of the Bayesian setup. He starts of by the introduction below and after a few examples of uses of Bayesian estimators he outlines the idea (after dots in my photo). I don't know what he means by: $EL(\Theta,d)$.

In my opinion there should be two expectations there since we want to find d to minimize (1.1), I can't see how minimizing the one above being sufficient. I've tried with "Law of total expectation" and Fubini but nothing has been satisfactory. I have a similar problem with a theorem which comes right after the second paragraph.

[image]

Comment: What is "Lehmanns book"? Can you make the figure larger, so it's easier to read?

Comment: The reference to posterior risk at the end makes it clear that the expression $EL(\Theta,d)$ is the expected loss of state $\Theta$ with decision $d$.

Comment: @whuber well the bayes risk (1.1) is $E_{\Lambda}E_{\theta} L[\theta,\delta]$, then why is this minimize given $EL(\Theta,d)$ is?  I suppose they mean this is $E_{\Lambda}L(\Theta,d)$  btw

Comment: Yes; Lehmann took pains to emphasize that $\Theta$ is governed by the distribution $\Lambda$, so this is the distribution involved in the expectation. The question he is answering is, how small can you make the risk by means of your choice of $d$?  You might be over-interpreting this situation, which involves nothing more complicated than that idea.

Comment: @whuber but why is $E_{\theta}$ "overlooked" doing this?

Comment: "Overlooked" in what sense?  Lehmann explicitly takes expectations, both in the *prior* and *posterior* cases he describes.

Comment: @whuber $E_{\Lambda} E_{\theta}L(\theta,\delta) \ne E_{\Lambda} L(\Theta,d)$ right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Fubini's theorem in action: when minimising in $\delta$
$$\mathbb{E_{\Lambda}} \{\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[L(\theta,\delta)]\}=\int_\Theta\int_\mathcal{X} L(\theta,\delta(x))\text{d}P_\theta(x)\text{d}\Lambda(\theta)=\int_\mathcal{X} \int_\Theta L(\theta,\delta(x))\text{d}\Lambda_x(\theta)\text{d}P(x)$$where $\Lambda_x$ denotes the posterior distribution of $\theta$ conditional on $x$, one minimises in $d$ for each value of $x$ the posterior expected loss
$$\int_\Theta L(\theta,d)\text{d}\Lambda_x(\theta)$$and set 
$$\delta(x)=\arg\min_d \int_\Theta L(\theta,d)\text{d}\Lambda_x(\theta)$$assuming all quantities are finite.

Comment: So $\Lambda$ is prior after the first equality? The subscripts confuses me, I tought there expressionen for prior and post where almost the same(of the form in your answer), and that one just changed the distribution of $\Lambda$ in post.

Comment: $\Lambda$ denotes the prior and $\lambda_x$ the posterior, while $P_\theta$ denotes the sampling distribution and $P$ the marginal.